# How rare is it to get a flat world with floating islands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I was playing the Minecraft java edition and decided to make a super flat world but then realised that a bunch of floating islands had generated as well
How rare is this?

Comment: This isn't detailed enough.

Comment: I made a flat world but it also spawned floating islands

Comment: could you add pictures?

Comment: And what blocks did you use? As said above, a screenshot would help.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible. It is possible you gotten one via a glitch (typically in Minecraft 1.12 or lower) or a really skinny cliff.

Comment: I was using forge 1.16.5

Answer (score 0):

I've got one using Minecraft version 1.16.5 on World seed: -182236734

I've found that it's definitely possible to generate one, but it's *very* hard to do so.